# Adding div element to body or document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a light box in pure JavaScript. For that I am making an overlay. I want to add this overlay to body but I also want to keep the content on the page. My current code adds the overlay div but it also removes the current contents in body. **How to add div element and keep contents on body?**

```
var el = document.getElementById('element');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
el.innerHTML = '<p><a id="clickme" href="#">Click me</a></p>';
document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>';
}
```

Comment: have you try to append it like : document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>'+document.body.innerHTML;

Answer (score 216, accepted):

## Try this out:-

**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/vmfbA/**

Use

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>';
```

instead of

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>';
```

**Edit:-**
Ideally you should use `body.appendChild` method instead of changing the `innerHTML`

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000';
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: You need to consider that doing document.body.innerHTML = 'something' incurs in a lot of unnecessary computation because the browser needs to parse the 'something' string and that takes a lot in a big page. A much more performant approach is to create the new element and attach it to the DOM. Check this comparision on jsperf: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-appendchild2

Comment: This approach will have some unwanted side effects as well. For example, all the bound events on child elements will become unbound once you set `innerHTML` afresh.

Comment: This is definitely the wrong answer... the question asks about adding an element, not rewriting the whole page, see JPH's for a better alternative.

Comment: -1. This is an awful way to achieve this. If you are reading this, do not use this slow and dated solution. Look at the answer by @peter-t

Comment: Not only is this slow, but destroys the earlier elements, so any event listeners attached to the page earlier are lost!  Avoid doing this at all costs. Use appendChild instead.

Comment: Despite using appenChild is the right way it seems innerHTML is faster. [comparison](https://image.ibb.co/byEEsy/Screenshot_186.png) Regardless of this result **do use appendChild**.

Comment: @lowtechsun I'd imagine that gets slower as innerHTML gets bigger

Comment: it is a wrong solution

Answer (score 315):

Using Javascript

```
var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
elemDiv.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;';
document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
```

Using jQuery

```
$('body').append('<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>');
```

Comment: strangest thing. at my worst, pure javascript has always been the way to do anything I wanted to do.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the only answer that goes about this in the correct way.

Comment: @MacroMan Even the jquery version? I'm using jquery and would like to do it properly that way too. (Just making sure because his jquery answer is only one line and doesn't seem to create a node or anything.)

Comment: @felwithe The jQuery version is acceptable, but you may wish to create a node from scratch and apply the styles individually if you need more clarity in your code.

Comment: `appendChild()` and `insertBefore()` give even more flexibility on the location of the element to be inserted

Comment: I'm getting `document.body is null` if script is added in header.

Answer (score 24):

*improving the post of @Peter T, by gathering all solutions together at one place.*

**[Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)**

```
function myFunction() {
    window.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<div id="myID" style="color:blue;"> With some data...</div>' );
}
function addElement(){
    var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
    elemDiv.style.cssText = 'width:100%;height:10%;background:rgb(192,192,192);';
    elemDiv.innerHTML = 'Added element with some data'; 
    window.document.body.insertBefore(elemDiv, window.document.body.firstChild);
    // document.body.appendChild(elemDiv); // appends last of that element
}
function addCSS() {
    window.document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML += ".mycss {text-align:center}";
}
```

*Using [`XPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201731/5081877) find the position of the Element in the DOM Tree and insert the specified text at a specified position to an XPath_Element. try this code over browser console.*

```
function insertHTML_ByXPath( xpath, position, newElement) {
    var element = document.evaluate(xpath, window.document, null, 9, null ).singleNodeValue;
    element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, newElement);
    element.style='border:3px solid orange';
}

var xpath_DOMElement = '//*[@id="answer-33669996"]';
var childHTML = '<div id="Yash">Hi My name is <B>\"YASHWANTH\"</B></div>';
var position = 'beforeend';
insertHTML_ByXPath(xpath_DOMElement, position, childHTML);
```

Answer (score 23):

Instead of replacing everything with innerHTML try:

`document.body.appendChild(myExtraNode);`

Comment: Note that you can get to the body simply by doing `document.body`.

Comment: This is a better solution.

Answer (score 11):

The most underrated method is `insertAdjacentElement`.
You can literally add your HTML using one single line.

```
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', html)
```

Read about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement

Answer (score 8):

The modern way is to use [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append), like so:

```js
let element = document.createElement('div');
element.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;';
document.body.append(element);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000;"></div>'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your `div` HTML code and set it directly into `body`(Or any element) with following code:

```
var divStr = '<div class="text-warning">Some html</div>';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += divStr;
```

Comment: the best and easiest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best and better way is to create an element and append it to the `body` tag.
Second way is to first get the `innerHTML` property of `body` and add code with it. For example:

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
b.innerHTML = b.innerHTML + "Your code";
```

Comment: Firstly, you can get to the page body by simply doing `document.body`, secondly as I mentioned before, don't rewrite the whole page just to append an element.

Answer (score -4):

Here's a really quick trick:
Let's say you wanna add p tag inside div tag.

```
<div>
<p><script>document.write(<variablename>)</script></p>
</div>
```

And that's it.