# How to append element to body?

Tags: javascript

Im currently using the following code to append a div to the body:

```
$("body").append('<div class="tooltip" id="op" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; height: 16px; width: 16px; top:70px"><span>Test</span></div>');
```

How could I do the same as above but without the use of `jQuery`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding div element to body or document in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741006/adding-div-element-to-body-or-document-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In pure Javascript it's going to be a little bit more verbose:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'tooltip';
div.id = 'op';
div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; z-index: 999; height: 16px; width: 16px; top:70px';
div.innerHTML = '<span>Test</span>';

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 5):

I really like the insertAdjacentHTML method for all modern browsers -- and there is support for older browsers as well.

Reference: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/insertAdjacentHTML-Everywhere

Usage:

```
var html = '<div class="tooltip" id="op" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; height: 16px; width: 16px; top:70px"><span>Test</span></div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do a lot with DOM! You can manipulate simple html this way!

Check out the W3 website :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score -1):

A simpler way would be

```
var t = document.createElement('div')
t.innerHTML = '<div class="tooltip" id="op" style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; height: 16px; width: 16px; top:70px"><span>Test</span></div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", t);
```

Read about insertAdjacentElement here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement