# How to append element after the body tag?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: img]

This is what I want.
I want the new created element append after the body tag.Not inside the body tag.

Thanks you.

Comment: This is not a code factory. Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: This is something you really shouldn't do. But theoretically, you can just call `document.appendChild()`. But, again, you shouldn't. All content on a page should be inside the body; putting content outside it can lead to upredictable behavior in different browsers.

Comment: I have tried,`document.appendChild()` but it's not working.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? Just curious.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: @muecas It is not a pure code factory, but still it is a code factory ;-)

Comment: Because I think it would not affect by other css but itself.
I have problem with the css. By the way I am building a Firefox extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding div element to body or document in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741006/adding-div-element-to-body-or-document-in-javascript)

Comment: @N.Jadhav : That would append to the body tag.

Comment: If it's not `document.appendChild()` then there should be some property of `document` which corresponds to the HTML tag (it might be `documentElement`), so you can call `appendChild()` if you need to; try researching `window.document`. I would honestly recommend rethinking your CSS though, but it's your call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `document.documentElement` to do the appending.

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(new_div);
```

This is how the `<html>` element is represented in the DOM.

---

This will not *necessarily* put it directly after the `body`. If that's needed, then you'd use `.insertBefore` instead of `.appendChild`.

```
document.documentElement.insertBefore(new_div, document.body.nextSibling);
```

---

Or you can use `.insertAdjacentElement`.

```
document.body.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", new_div);
```

---

If you're creating the new element using HTML markup in your JS, then you can use `.insertAdjacentHTML`.

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div>...</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.id = "id";
div.innerHTML = "1223";
document.body.parentNode.insertBefore(div, document.body.nextSibling);
```