# HTML into Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have this code:

```
if(pageStatus === 'online'){
        //html here?
```

What I would like to do is: if page status is online, some HTML code will go inside, I would like to add a button (I have the CSS, it's just putting it in there). How can this be done? I thought I could break out the JS but I know that won't work.

//in regards to it saying this has already been answered, I have looked at the other topics and have no idea, people here are helping me for my issue directly, the topic is a little different to what I want it to do.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: If you want to do what I think you want to do, you'll need to create the element in JS and append it to the HTML element you want it to appear inside.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I've seen that but got no clue, aha.

Comment: @Christian4423 If you have an answer, post it. It's frowned upon to ask users to PM you.

Comment: Perhaps https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/ is easier to grok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding div element to body or document in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741006/adding-div-element-to-body-or-document-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you need to hard-code an element (`div`) where you want to insert a code.

Now, you need to visualize the position names. Here how it works:

```
<!-- beforebegin -->
<div>
  <!-- afterbegin -->
  foo
  <!-- beforeend -->
</div>
<!-- afterend -->
```

Now, you can insert the code relative to the `div` element.  Here's a quick example:

```
// <div id="one">one</div>
var d1 = document.getElementById('one');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');

// At this point, the new structure is:
// <div id="one">one</div><div id="two">two</div>
```

> ## Security Considerations
>
> When inserting HTML into a page by using insertAdjacentHTML be careful not to >use user input that hasn't been escaped.
>
> It is recommended you not use insertAdjacentHTML when inserting plain text; >instead, use the node.textContent property or node.insertAdjacentText() method. >This doesn't interpret the passed content as HTML, but instead inserts it as >raw text.

**Traditional Method**

Simply, select a div and use `innerHTML` property. Here's a quick example:

```
  if(pageStatus === 'online'){
    document.getElementById('insertHere').innerHTML = '<p>Server is online</p>';
  }
```

Putting it all together:

```js
var pageStatus = 'online';

if(pageStatus === 'online') {
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">Goto Website</a>";
  // Since, HTML attribute doesn't support single quotes, '\' is used to escape the double quotes.
} else {
 document.getElementById('test').innerText = 'You can\'t proceed because page is currently offline';
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Learn more about escaping the characters: [What does it mean to escape a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646142/what-does-it-mean-to-escape-a-string)

Comment: Ok, so where you say select a div, I am confused there. Sorry I am new to JavaScript aha

Comment: @Tom It's called [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)! You can pick an element from your raw HTML code and handle it with Javascript. For example: let's say you have a paragraph. You give id to that element by adding a attribute `id` or `class` to the element `<p id="para" class="paragraph"></p>`! And then you select that element using Javascript: `document.getElementById('para')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph')[0]`. `[0]` means select the first element because one class can be used multiple times in different elements.

Comment: I put this `<a href="https://google.com" id="href">Google</a>` then `document.getElementById('href').innerHTML = '<a href="https://google.com" id="href">Google</a>';` but the `ahref` in raw HTML is always showing.

Comment: Where do you want to insert the HTML code? As per your comment, I am seeing that you want to insert HTML inside of `ahref`!

Comment: I would like it so, if the page is online, it will output a href link. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks so much! That worked, however, when I tried to put my own code in, it broke, where you have `<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">Goto Website</a>` I have put `<a href=\"https://tawk.to/chat/5b190d248859f57bdc7bee43/default/?$_tawk_popout=true\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"button raised bg-blue-500 color-white\">` - any idea?

Comment: @Tom You forgot to close the `a` tag! Try this: `"<a href=\"https://tawk.to/chat/5b190d248859f57bdc7bee43/default/?$_tawk_popout=true\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"button raised bg-blue-500 color-white\">Link</a>"`

Answer (score -1):

Since we don't know where you want to add, let's add to the body of the document.
You can add to any specific location by doing something like: `parentElement = document.getElementById("someId")` , etc and the create a button as I have shown and add append it to the `parentElement`

```js
var pageStatus = "online"
if(pageStatus === 'online'){ 

    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    // gets the body of the document/
    // you can get any specific element as the parent element similary...
    button = document.createElement('button')
    // creates a button
    button.innerHTML = "Click Me!"
    // sets the text you weant to dispaly on the button
     button.setAttribute("onclick","location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/9335017/tom'" );
    body.appendChild(button)

}
```

Comment: Where is the link where the button directs? I need it to be an ahref

Comment: @Tom: ?? Are you not able to get redirected to another loaction on the ``button` click after you `Run code snippet`?

Comment: Hmmm, I can see Click me in there

Answer (score -1):

You could just have a css class like the following:

```
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add this to the html you want to initially hide, or toggle using an if/else.

```
<div id="online-toggle"></div>
```

Then in your JavaScript you can do something simple like:

```
if (pageStatus === 'online') {
    document.getElementById("online-toggle").classList.remove("display-none");
} else {
    document.getElementById("online-toggle").classList.add("display-none");
}
```

or in older browsers:

```
if (pageStatus === 'online') {
    var regex = new RegExp('(\\s|^)display-none(\\s|$)');
    el.className = el.className.replace(regex, '');
}
```

Alternatively you can build the html manually in JavaScript using something like:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Or use some form of Ajax call that returns a template or view that you can embed in the desired location.

Comment: This would not work for me, as the actually thing is being loaded by javascript already.

Comment: @Tom You could do the opposite and add the CSS class on the else, but if not Sanjay's response using innerHtml would probably be your best option then, good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Chris - I am just confused on how to "select a div" and that part of it all.

Answer (score -3):

So it isn't very good practice but you can use

```
document.write("some html")
```

```html
some html before js
 
<script>
var a =1;

if(a==1)
{

document.write("<button>button 1</button>");
}

if(a==2)
{

document.write("<button>button 2</button>");
}

</script>

some html after JS
```

Comment: Document.write will replace all existing html

Comment: It is a BAD practice, suggesting stuff like this to a newbie is like killing a kitten.