# Is it possible to append a group of html to html page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make it so i can append this html below :

```
      <div  class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color: #ff5100;"></i></div>
          <h4 class="title"><a href="">Title Of Box</a></h4>
          <p class="description">Description Of Box</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Im trying to append that code several times within a html page but i cant find a way, iv spent 4 hours looking this up, and found nothing :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741006/adding-div-element-to-body-or-document-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would need a few parts. A working easy example:

```js
var stuff = '<div  class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 wow bounceInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s">'+
            '<div class="box">'+
             ' <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color: #ff5100;"></i></div>'+
              '<h4 class="title"><a href="">Title Of Box</a></h4>'+
              '<p class="description">Description Of Box</p>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'
          
    var add = function(){
  
      document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += stuff;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="add()">add </button>
```

Assuming vanilla Js above:

But the variable *stuff* is a string.

On some event, in this case a button click we get that string and append the dom element with that string.

I used a element Id as the selector, but you could also use a class, an event to get a parent or sibling element etc..

Then you use **innerHtml** to append (or replace if you wanted) the string into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Element.prototype.insertAdjacentHTML`.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML. (Note that MDN will be down for maintenance for up to an hour later today.)

```js
const myContainer = document.getElementById("some-element");
const myNewHtml = "<div><span>Inserted by JS</span></div>";
myContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", myNewHtml);
```

```html
<div id="some-element">
  <span>Static content</span>
</div>
```

**Edit**
Note: A common alternative to this is to build the HTML entirely in JavaScript, using the `createElement`, `createTextNode`, and `appendChild` methods.
(I think the reason the this more complicated technique is common is that -- while inserting a pre-written string of HTML with `insertAdjacentHTML` is very convenient -- if your pre-written HTML is not written properly, you won't see any error messages until your script either fails at runtime or just inserts a nonsensical string into your page.)